# Run function on link, send user to pre-link ad page, ad page redirects user after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page with a bunch of links like so:

```
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight"  href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/17waystokillboss.swf" id="link" onclick="doalert(); return false;><span class="wsite-button-inner">17 Ways To Kill Your Boss(NEW)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight"  href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/24waystokyb.swf" id="link" onclick="doalert(); return false;><span class="wsite-button-inner">24 Ways To Kill Your Boss(NEW)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight"  href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/4-wheel-madness.swf" id="link" onclick="doalert(); return false;><span class="wsite-button-inner">4 Wheel Madness</a><br> 
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight"  href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/Achilles.swf" id="link" onclick="doalert(); return false;><span class="wsite-button-inner">Achillies(NEW)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight"  href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/alien_hominid.swf" id="link" onclick="doalert(); return false;><span class="wsite-button-inner">Alien Hominid(NEWER)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight"  href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/asteroids.swf" id="link" onclick="doalert(); return false;><span class="wsite-button-inner">Asteriods(NEW)</a><br>
```

Script running this page to send to adpage:

```
<script>
function doalert() {
var str1 = "http://www.goldandblack.net/adpage.html#";

    window.location.href = str1.concat(document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href")));
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Script on adpage to forward to clicked page:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var str2 = window.location.href;
var str3 = str2.replace("http://www.goldandblack.net/adpage.html#", "");
window.location.href = str3;
};

</script>
```

This isn't working for some reason

Comment: You never, by no means, should repeat the value of any `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` attribute should be unique for any element. so having all the elements `id="link"` will cause problems.

What you may do instead is to remove the `id` attribute and send the element self to the `doalert()` function like this `doalert(this)`.

So your html part will be like this:

```
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/17waystokillboss.swf" onclick="doalert(this); return false;"><span class="wsite-button-inner">17 Ways To Kill Your Boss(NEW)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/24waystokyb.swf" onclick="doalert(this); return false;"><span class="wsite-button-inner">24 Ways To Kill Your Boss(NEW)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/4-wheel-madness.swf" onclick="doalert(this); return false;"><span class="wsite-button-inner">4 Wheel Madness</a><br> 
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/Achilles.swf" onclick="doalert(this); return false;"><span class="wsite-button-inner">Achillies(NEW)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/alien_hominid.swf" onclick="doalert(this); return false;"><span class="wsite-button-inner">Alien Hominid(NEWER)</a><br>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/asteroids.swf" onclick="doalert(this); return false;"><span class="wsite-button-inner">Asteriods(NEW)</a><br>
```

And then change your JavaScript function `doalert()` and add the parameter to it like this: `doalert(obj)` and then use `obj` instead of `document.getElementById("link")`

So your JavaScript part will be like this:

```
<script>
function doalert(obj) {
    var str1 = "http://www.goldandblack.net/adpage.html#";
    window.location.href = str1.concat(obj.getAttribute("href"));
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Also you can get the `Location hash Property` with this line: `window.location.hash`

And then it will return the *anchor part of a URL* with a `#` at the beginning. So we get it and remove the `#` char at the beginning.

So your `script` in the `adpage.html` file would be like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var str3 = window.location.hash;
    str3 = str3.substring(1); // remove the first char from string
    window.location.href = str3;
};
</script>
```

Comment: <script>
    function doalert(obj) {
    var str1 = "http://www.goldandblack.net/adpage.html#";
    window.location.href = str1.concat(obj.getAttribute("href")));
    return false;
};
    </script>
There appears to be something wrong with this code. And its not the extra paranthesis in ("href)))

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I just copy and pasted your code and did not see the extra **)**. Actually the extra ) exists in your own code! I foxed my code. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately im still getting a syntax error. This time it looks to be something wrong with the links on the page..
 Here is my updated code:

Comment: <a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight"  href="/uploads/7/0/9/4/70947887/custom_themes/436120861689278040/files/Games/interactivebuddy.swf" onclick="doalert(this); return false;><span class="wsite-button-inner">Interactive Buddy</a><br>

Comment: OK, another typo, and again it was in your original code! at this section of the html `onclick="doalert(this); return false;>` ther is a double quote missing! So it should be like this: `onclick="doalert(this); return false;">`. I've edited my answer and fixed it as well

Comment: Thank you so much for the help +1